# How do i link a Texture image button to another screen?

Tags: java, libgdx

**1) How do I set the "playbuttonactive" to go to the gamescreen upon clicking on the texture and as for "exitbtn" texture would be exiting the game?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that `playbuttonActive` and `exitbutton` are textures that are drawn on the screen. If that's the case you just need to check where the screen was touched:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
  Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0); // get the position of the input event
  camera.unproject(touchPos); // converts screen coordinates to world coordinates
  
  if (isWithinPlayButtonActiveCoordinates(touchPos)) {
    // change to the game screen
    game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
    dispose();
  }
  else if (isWithinExitButtonCoordinates(touchPos)) {
    // close the application
    Gdx.app.exit();
  }
}
```